# check for the serial port data untill its done

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, serial-port

i am creating multiple graphs using serial data.i am separating the serial data with split() function and assigning each and every data to a different variables using this code.it works fine.But,sometimes in the starting of the program the received data from the serial port is less in numbers.It creates index error.how can i tell my code to wait for all the serial port data.For,example the number of data send from the serial port is six.The program should wait till all the six data has been received.And using the data am plotting different graphs in a loop.i need to save each and every graph in different name.

am using python 3.5 , matplotlib for graph.i have been tried to save a single graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
import serial

plt.ion()
s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)


def graph():
    ser = s.readline()
    i = ser.split()
    q = (int(i[0]))
    w = (int(i[1]))
    e = (int(i[2]))
    r = (int(i[3]))
    t = (int(i[4]))
    u = (int(i[5]))
    print(q,w,e,r,t,u)
    print(i)
    y =(q,w,e,r,t,u)
    x=(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    plt.ylabel("pressure(psi)")
    plt.xlabel('Number of Sensors')
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.draw()
    plt.savefig('books_read.png')
    plt.pause(1)
    plt.clf()
while True:
    graph()
```

i expect the program should wait for all the data at the first time.And save each and every graph.

Comment: If you know that you are waiting for 6 inputs can't you just do a quick length check to make sure the data length is 6? i.e. `if len(y) == 6: continue` ... and if not you could do a small loop to check until it is 6.

Comment: can to suggest me with editing my post